# CSS Hover Out / Mouse Out Transition?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am having a problem with mouse out transition I have used a few examples from similar questions but had no luck as it is a slightly different case:

When the page loads I have a menu bar with one of the options triggering a hidden div:

```
.top-links div.musictest {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    }
```

The particular option when hovered triggers div.musictest to display as a block.

```
.top-links li.music:hover + div.musictest {
        display:block;
    }
```

So when this drop down div.musictest is displaying as a block to maintain it showing as it includes options itself to be clicked I have CSS to say:

```
.top-links div.musictest:hover {
     display:block;
    }
```

So here is my problem, from everywhere I have read if I want .top-links div.musictest to fade out when I stop hovering it needs a transition delay however when I put one in nothing happens as I believe display:none is stopping it from fading out. But without the display:none it shows the hidden div.musictest always.

At the moment the code above works fine if I want the hidden div to disappear immediately, but I am wanting it to have a transition time before disappearing.

Any ways around this or am I putting it in the wrong place completely?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: That is all the css for the particular part.
And here is the html for the same part:
 `<div class="top-links">
             <toplinks>   
                                    <ul id="menu">
                                    <li>Home</li>       
                                      <li class="music"></li>   
                                     <div class="musictest">`

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle, so i could see how it works and what doesn't?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/212zeg0u/
Well it all works when hover li class="music" it shows the div class="musictest" when hover div class="musictest" is maintains showing div class="musictest" when stop hovering div class="musictest" is disappears instantly I'm trying to make it delay for a second before it disappears.
Thanks Shlomi

Comment: You cannot animate the display proeprty, that's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the opacity of the div to zero so it won't be visible but it's still a in display mode block and when your mouse is out of the element it's start to fade out as you wanted.

Add this to your css:

```
.top-links li.music:hover + div.musictest {

       opacity:1;
       transition: opacity 0.1s;
       -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s;
       -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.1s;
    }

  .top-links li.music + div.musictest {
       opacity:0;
       display:block;
       transition: opacity 2s;
       -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
       -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
       -o-transition: opacity 2s;
    }
```

And here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/212zeg0u/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `opacity: 0` instead of `display: none`

(Edit: I just read your title again, you can check [this link](https://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/) for only fade out)

So here is an example with both:

```css
.top-links li.music:hover {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
.top-links li.music:hover + div.musictest {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.top-links div.musictest {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 44px;
  width: 800px;
  left: 22px;
}
.top-links div.musictest:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-links">
  <toplinks>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li class="music">Music</li>
      <div class="musictest">
        Show when hover li class="music"
      </div>
    </ul>
  </toplinks>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks! this is perfect is there a way to make it stop fading if mouse hovers back over like a second chance thing incase your mouse stopped hovering by accident?

Comment: The only thing I know of is that you could add a `transition-delay: 2s` so the fade out starts later, (but I am a newbie to Website design so there will most likely be another, better way too)

And I moved the `opacity: 1;` to `.top-links li.music:hover + div.musictest`so it reacts on hovering on the <li> and not the <div>